# Windows says "access denied" when copying files from one partition to another

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive

I have a PC with two XP systems on it. I need to recover files from the old broken system to the new one – it's on another partition but on the same hard drive.

When I try open that folder it tells me "access denied".

What can I do?

Comment: Why don't you just a scandisk/chkdsk on the "broken" partition, and reassign the owner of all files to your user, so you can access the partition without problems, or, alternatively gain more knowledge about the problem during the process?

Answer (score 3):

For dealing such problems, I tend to use the [Knoppix](http://knoppix.de/) Live CD. It got me out of quite some situations...

Just boot the Knoppix, and then you have full control on what and where you copy.

Comment: any linux livecd will work. You do not have to worry about windows permissions... using a linux based os... http://www.livecdlist.com/

Comment: @Logman is right, Knoppix is not the only one for this job...

Answer (score 1):

You need to take ownership of the folder within the NTFS permissions settings.

Comment: Can you expand your answer and explain how to do that exactly?

Comment: Right click the folder you want to access and hit properties. Under the security tab select advanced and then "owner." Change this to your current user account and your golden. If you are running the Home Edition of XP and not the professional version you need to log into safe mode and use the default administrator account.

Comment: To add a bit to this answer, it says access denied because the user account that owns the files exists on one XP system, and not the other. Therefore, the account you are logging in as doesn't have permission to move the files because they belong to the other XP user(even though you are both).